# Equations in $\mathbb{R^n}$ dimensions.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

If i have a linear Equation, 
$$ a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+...+a_nx_n=b,$$
Could this be geometrically represented in a 'n-dimensional' plane ($\mathbb{R^n}$)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Almost.  If $b=0$ it is the $n-1$ dimensional subspace consisting of all vectors orthogonal to $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n)$.  If $b \neq 0$ it is a parallel $n-1$ dimensional object set off in the $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n)$ direction from the origin.

Comment: What does orthogonal mean. I have just started to revise\'learn' about how linear algebra. Is there a recommended textbook, or online source where I could read more about this topic?

Comment: They are at an angle of $\frac \pi 2$ from each other or the dot product of two vectors is zero.

Comment: "orthogonal" is the more formal word for "perpendicular"

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The set of solutions $(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to the homogeneous equation
$$a_1 x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n = 0$$
is an $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane, specifically the hyperplane orthogonal to the vector $\vec{a} = (a_1,...,a_n)$. The solution to the inhomogeneous equation
$$a_1 x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n = b$$
is an affine hyperplane, parallel to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the $a_i$ are.

If at least one of the $a_i$ is $\neq 0$ then this is a hyperplane.